# How to properly extend django User model

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I'm trying to extend the default Django's authentication model with additional fields and functionaliy, so I've decided to just go with extending User model and writing my own authentication backend.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class MyUser(User):
    access_key = models.CharField(_('Acces Key'), max_length=64)
```

This is really a basic code yet when trying to syncdb I'm cetting a strange error that Google doesn't know about :

`CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
core.sldcuser: 'user_ptr' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.`

In my settings.py I've added what I guess is required :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.MyUser'
```

Had anyone stumbled upon this error ?

Or maybe I should use a one-to-one way, or a hybrid of 1t1 with proxy ?

Comment: what's the core determine here exactly it's a apps ?

Comment: shouldn't you be extending `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser` instead since these are the models with `abstract = True`?

Comment: I didn't even knew about those classes so not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're doing right now, is creating a subclass of User, which is non-abstract. This means creating a table that has a `ForeignKey` called `user_ptr` pointing at the primary key on the `auth.User` table. *However*, what you're also doing by setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is telling `django.contrib.auth` not to create that table, because you'll be using `MyUser` instead. Django is understandably a little confused :P

What you need to do instead is inherit either from `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`.

- Use `AbstractUser` if you want everything that User has already, and just want to add more fields
- Use `AbstractBaseUser` if you want to start from a clean state, and only inherit generic functions on the User, but implement your own fields.

REF:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: thanks. Last time I've used Django few years back I guess there was no such thing as those Abstract models

Comment: Abstract models have been around since [at least 1.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes). I'm glad this helped you out though. Happy Hunting :D